# How to use copy assignment operator with linked list c++

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have to use copy constructor and copy assignment operator to test a linked list.

list1 has 3 doubles appended to it

list2 = list1  where the copy constructor comes in.

List4 = list3 = list1 is where the copy assignment operator comes in.

then list4 has 1 more double appended to it.

This is the class i have been given.

```
// Specification file for the NumberList class
#ifndef NUMBERLIST_H
#define NUMBERLIST_H

class NumberList
{
private:
   // Declare a structure for the list
   struct ListNode
   {
      double value;           // The value in this node
      struct ListNode *next;  // To point to the next node
   }; 

   ListNode *head;            // List head pointer

public:
   // Constructor
   NumberList()
        { head = NULL; }
   
   //TO DO: Add the copy constructor 
   NumberList(const NumberList& origObject);

   //TO DO: Add the overloaded assignment operatora
   NumberList& operator=(const NumberList& objToCopy);

   // Destructor
   ~NumberList();
      
   // Linked list operations
   void appendNode(double);
   void insertNode(double);
   void displayList() const;
};
#endif
```

I have a simple copy constructor that does what it has to. When i execute the program the constructor seems to do what is has to do. I assume its because it's only one time the copy constructor is used.

```
NumberList::NumberList(const NumberList& origObject){
   
   cout << "copy constructor called." << endl;
   head = new ListNode;
   *head = *(origObject.head);
}
```

An this is the copy assignment operator that i have

```
NumberList& NumberList::operator=(const NumberList& objToCopy){
   cout << "overlaoded operator" << endl;
   if(this != &objToCopy){
      head = new ListNode;
      
      ListNode* nodePtr = new ListNode;
      nodePtr = objToCopy.head;
      nodePtr->next = NULL;

      ListNode* temp = objToCopy.head->next;
      while(temp){
         nodePtr->next = new ListNode;
         nodePtr->next = temp;
         nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
         nodePtr->next = NULL;

         temp = objToCopy.head->next;
      }
   }

   return *this;
}
```

This is what it displays after the copy assignment is activated list4=list3=list1.

```
After inserting 5.5 to list4, List1 is: 
1.6

After inserting 5.5 to list4, List3 is: 
0

After inserting 5.5 to list4, List4 is: 
0
5.5
```

Here is what. its supposed to look like after the operator is used.

```
After inserting 5.5 to list4, List1 is: 
1.6
4.8
7.9

After inserting 5.5 to list4, List3 is: 
1.6
4.8
7.9

After inserting 5.5 to list4, List4 is: 
1.6
4.8
5.5
7.9
```

I feel like the more i think about it the less i understand even the code i wrote. So i have basically been writing things hoping it works.

---

Comment: I recommending using a raw pointer strictly as a non-owning pointer, and using a `std::unique_ptr` as an owning pointer.

Comment: `head = new ListNode;`... But what if the current list is not empty? What happens with the old list with that assignment?

Comment: *"list1 has 3 doubles appended to it"* -- You may want to verify your code with a list of length 1 before testing with anything longer. You do need to test longer lists, but if there are any bugs that show up with a list of length 1, they will be easier to debug with less data to track.

Comment: *"I have a simple copy constructor that does what it has to."* -- Good. Then you can probably leave the definition out of your [mre]. Keep the declaration, but omit the definition (as long as the linker does not complain). Focus on the piece that is malfunctioning. **Keep it simple.** Based on your output, it looks like you need only a single assignment to reproduce the bug. So you might be able to use something like `int main() { NumberList list1; NumberList list3; list1.appendNode(1.6); list1.displayList(); list3 = list1; list1.displayList(); }` to run your question's *example* code.

Comment: Your copy constructor doesn't do _"what it has to"_.  It only copies the first node of the list.  The rest are all shared between the original and the copy.  Beyond that, you really need to include a [mcve] in your question.  It's very hard to tell you what your code is doing wrong when we can't see that code.

Comment: @MilesBudnek is the copy constructor having an error affect the copy assignment operator? Because it looks like it works when it displays list1 and list2 after llist2=list1.

Comment: @Mindset Of course they'll look the same; they're sharing all of the same nodes (except the first).  You need to loop through all of the nodes and copy them one-by-one like you do in your copy assignment operator.  If you don't, then adding a node to either the original or the copy will in effect add it to _both_.  You'll also probably end up with double-free errors (assuming you're properly `delete`ing your nodes).

Comment: made a new copy constructor and tested it by appending things to list1 and list2 and it seems to work better than the one i had before. Still need to do the copy assignment operator.

Comment: As a beginner, always start with **rule of 3** and implement it with **copy/swap**. Leave further optimizations to when you get more experienced. The **idioms** above are famous; just google them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `appendNode` have been tested and works, I would recommend a simple loop over the source list and then just call `appendNode` on the current list:

```
for (auto* node = objToCopy.head; node; node = node->next)
{
    appendNode(node->value);
}
```

This one single loop will copy the whole of the source list.

Remember to free the old list first.

---

To make `appendNode` simpler and more efficient, and not have to iterate over the whole list when you want to append a node, I recommend you also store a pointer to the list tail.

Comment: Sorry but vs code is warning me that auto is a c++11 extension and idk how to change that so i can't try that loop.

Comment: @Mindset You can safely ignore these kinds of warnings and just compile. And if your environment doesn't support C++11 for some stupid reason you can replace "auto" with "ListNode".

Comment: @Mindset That could mean one of two things: Either you have a *very* old compiler which doesn't include support for the last 12 years of advances by default; Or you are on a macOS system using Clang which for some reason still defaults to the old C++03 standard. Either way you need to add the `-std=c++11` argument when building.